# Handling firebase authentication errors Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, authentication, dart

I'm trying to handle firebase authentication errors such as wrong password etc
But when I enter wrong password the app freezes and I get an exception but I want to display it in snackbar
Here is my code

```
Future <bool> sign InWithEmailAndPassword(String userEmail , String userPassword ) async {
 try {
 await _firebaseAuth.sign InWithEmailAndPassword (email : userEmail , password : userPassword );
 return true;
 } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
 print (e);
 return false;
 }
 }
```

And here

```
bool result = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword ( _emailController.text.trim() , _passwordController.text.trim ();

 if ( result == true ) {
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context) => HomeView ());
 } else {
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(' Something went wrong ! ' ));
 }
 }
```

And I tried to assign the value of the error I caught in a variable and check if it's null or not to display an error message but it didn't work !

Comment: What exception do you get?

Comment: Firebase exception the password is wrong or this email doesn't have a password

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this code, it should catch the error

```
   Future <bool> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String userEmail , String userPassword )async {
     try {
     await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (email : userEmail , password : userPassword );
     return true;
     } catch (error) {
      switch (error.code) {
          case "auth/invalid-email":
          case "auth/user-disabled":
          case "auth/user-not-found":
            print(error.message); //for email
            break;
          case "auth/wrong-password":
            print(error.message); // for password
            break;
        }
    }
     }
```

Or This should work as well to;

```
  Future <bool> signInWithEmailAndPassword(String userEmail , String userPassword )async {
    try {
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword (email : userEmail , password : userPassword );
      return "Success";
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      return e.message;
    } catch (e) {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: it didn't work both of them I tried many methods and I still get this error

Comment: I couldn't post a longer code here but here is the whole code https://github.community/t/handling-firebase-authentication-errors-flutter/175301

Comment: I didn't understand how did you use signInWithEmailAndPassword function that you created. you used auth that is an controller final _authController = context.watch<AuthController>();  how did you access your function by writing auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword. I see you use signIn method for it but I guess you can't access the function that you created. Can you write an print("hello") in signInWithEmailAndPassword to check really it is working. You can follow my code in githup to understand the concept  https://github.com/timurturbil/Firebase-with-Flutter

Comment: because i created a method for the sign in button and passed _authConttroller as a argument and received it in a var named auth i followed your code i coped and pasted it but i get the same error and in the console there is this error " Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null. "

Comment: you should check your internet connection. this error pops up due to weak internet connection